# Why does R column interval slicing not work when interval has length 1?

Tags: r, matrix, slice

I was running some code yesterday that involved slicing a matrix into intervals of columns. That is, given an nxp matrix A and a sequence of break points, I sliced A using a for loop. The first piece was A[,1:break_points[1]]. The second piece was A[,break_points[1]+1:break_points[2]]. The third piece was A[,break_points[2]+1:break_points[3]], etc.

Unfortunately, the execution ended in an error. After a bit of digging, I found the root of the problem: One of the column intervals was length 1. As it turns out, A[,3679:3679] does not work as expected. More specifically,

```
A0 <- A[,3679:3680]
ncol(A0)
> 2
```

but

```
A0 <- A[,3679:3679]
ncol(A0)
> NULL
```

I know how to fix this: Just create an if-else exception for the case that break_points[i+1] - break_points[i] = 1. But I'm curious why R treats column slices of length 1 differently in the first place.

Comment: It's probably just automatic type conversion. If you check with `class(A0)`, `A0` will probably be a vector of some sort depending on the values in there. You can coerce that object into a `matrix` like so `A0 <- as.matrix(A[,3679:3679])` (you can then check if the conversion succeeded with `class(A0)`), and `ncol(A0)` should then be `1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When subsetting a matrix, `R` by default converts slices of length 1 to a vector. To prevent this you have to or should add argument `drop = FALSE`, e.g. `A[ ,3679:3679, drop = FALSE]` will give you a one-column matrix instead of a vector. A discusion on simplyfing vs. preserving subsetting can be found in Hadley Wickham's Book [Advanced R](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Subsetting.html).